Minimize the maximum distance between nodes in a graph when each node is allowed a fixed number of connections?
There are N nodes, and each node is allowed to have K connections. How do you assign connections to minimize the maximum distance between any two nodes in the graph? Each node must be accessible from any other node via some traversal path. Distance is the number of connections traversed to move between two nodes.
We need K to be at least two in order to link all nodes in a circular pattern, but once K is 3 or more how can optimal links be determined?
Approximate solutions are also welcome if no exact solution is known.

Related: Degree-Diameter Problem. But since the optimal solutions to the problem are mostly unknown, I think the problem is hard.

This is an open problem, so I don't think any efficient algorithm to compute the answer is known.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_diameter_problem and http://combinatoricswiki.org/wiki/The_Degree/Diameter_Problem.
However, for small $N,K$, there are tables of known values.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_the_largest_known_graphs_of_a_given_diameter_and_maximal_degree and http://combinatoricswiki.org/wiki/The_Degree_Diameter_Problem_for_General_Graphs.
